# Problema con inicio de sesión seguro con PHP y Mysql con session y cookie

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, session, cookies

¡Hola! Estoy tratando de hacer un inicio de sesión (login) el cuál da la opción de guardar la sesión iniciada. El típico "Recuérdame en este equipo". Para que se inicie sesión nada más abrir la página aunque se haya cerrado el navegador.

Lo he intentado hacer creando una cookie segura que se guarde de la siguiente manera:

```php
public function checkInicioDeSesion($email, $contrasena, $recordarSesion){
        $tiempo_inicio = microtime(true);

        $contador = 0;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->TablaDb WHERE EMAIL=:email";

        $resultado = $this->Conexion->prepare($sql);

        $resultado->execute(array(":email"=>$email));

        while($registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo "<p>Email: " . $registro['EMAIL'] . " | Contraseña: " . $registro['CONTRASENA'] . "</p>";

            if(password_verify($contrasena,$registro['CONTRASENA'])){
                $cliente = new Cliente_Modelo();

                $cliente->setIdCliente($registro['IDCLIENTE']);
                $cliente->setEmail($registro['EMAIL']);
                $cliente->setContrasena($registro['CONTRASENA']);
                $cliente->setReloginCliente($registro['RELOGIN_CLIENTE']);
                $cliente->setNombreCliente($registro['NOMBRE_CLIENTE']);
                $cliente->setApellido1($registro['APELLIDO1']);
                $cliente->setApellido2($registro['APELLIDO2']);
                $cliente->setNifNie($registro['NIF_NIE']);
                $cliente->setTipoCliente($registro['TIPO_CLIENTE']);
                $cliente->setTelefono1($registro['TELEFONO1']);
                $cliente->setTelefono2($registro['TELEFONO2']);
                $cliente->setIdCliente($registro['IDCLIENTE']);

                $contador++;
            } else{
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump(password_verify($contrasena,$registro['CONTRASENA']));
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        }

        $refer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

        if($contador > 0){

            if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
                //echo "<p>No existe una sesión. Voy a iniciarla ahora.</p>";
                session_start();
            } else{
                //echo "<p>Ya existe una sesión.</p>";
            }

            $_SESSION['Cliente'] = $cliente->getNombreCliente();
            echo "<p>¡Has iniciado sesión correctamente!</p>
            <p>¡Bienvenido, " . $_SESSION['Cliente'] . "!</p>";
            print_r($_COOKIE);
            if($recordarSesion == true){
                $this->setRelogin($cliente->getEmail(), $cliente->getContrasena(), $cliente->getIdCliente());

                echo "<p>Se acaba de crear una cookie que tendrá una duración de 1 año.</p>";

                /*echo "<p>Contenido de la cookie loginCliente: {$_COOKIE['loginCliente']}</p>";*/
            }
            header("refresh:10;url=$refer");

            $tiempo_fin = microtime(true);
            echo "Tiempo empleado: " . ($tiempo_fin - $tiempo_inicio);
        } else{
            if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
                //echo "<p>No existe una sesión. Voy a iniciarla ahora.</p>";
                session_start();
            } else{
                //echo "<p>Ya existe una sesión.</p>";
            }
            echo "<p>¡Ha habido un error al intentar iniciar sesión!</p>
                <p>Por favor, asegúrate de haber escrito correctamente tanto el email como la contraseña.</p>";
            header("refresh:5;url=$refer");
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
```

La función setRelogin crea una coookie segura que luego guarda también en la base de datos:

```php
private function setRelogin($emailcliente, $contrasenacliente, $idcliente){
        $combinacionRelogin;
        $EmailCifrado = password_hash($emailcliente, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array("cost"=>15));
        $contraCifrada = password_hash($contrasenacliente, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array("cost"=>15));

        $combinacionRelogin = $EmailCifrado.$contraCifrada;

        $combinacionSeguraRelogin = password_hash($combinacionRelogin, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array("cost"=>15));

        setcookie("RLID", $combinacionRelogin, time()+60*60*24*365, "/");

        $sql = "UPDATE $this->TablaDb SET RELOGIN_CLIENTE=:ReloginCliente WHERE IDCLIENTE=:IdCliente";

        $preparar = $this->Conexion->prepare($sql);

        $preparar->bindValue(":ReloginCliente", $combinacionSeguraRelogin, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $preparar->bindValue(":IdCliente", $idcliente, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $resultado = $preparar->execute();

        if ($resultado) {
            echo "<p>¡Se ha actualizado correctamente el cliente!</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>¡Ha habido algún error intentando actualizar el cliente!</p>";
        }
    }
```

El problema llega cuando intento iniciar sesión con la opción de guardar sesión. Al parecer lo hace todo  bien. Si cierro la pestaña y abro la página en otra nueva pestaña no pasa nada. pero si cierro el navegador me dice que no encuentra `$_SESSION['Cliente']`;

La función que trata de iniciar sesión con la cookie es:

```php
public function checkRelogin(){

        $tiempo_inicio = microtime(true);

        if(isset($_COOKIE['RLID'])){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->TablaDb WHERE RELOGIN_CLIENTE=:ReloginCliente";

            $preparar = $this->Conexion->prepare($sql);
            $resultado = $preparar->execute(array(":ReloginCliente"=>$_COOKIE['RLID']));

            //$registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo "<pre>";
            echo "Edsgoigfoi";
            var_dump($resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
            echo "</pre>";


            /*if($registro){
                echo "<pre>";
                echo "el entone ";
                var_dump($registro);
                echo "</pre>";
            }*/


            while($registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                $cliente = new Cliente_Modelo();

                $cliente->setIdCliente($registro['IDCLIENTE']);
                echo "<p>Id del cliente: " . $cliente->getIdCliente() . "</p>";
                $cliente->setEmail($registro['EMAIL']);
                $cliente->setContrasena($registro['CONTRASENA']);
                $cliente->setReloginCliente($registro['RELOGIN_CLIENTE']);
                $cliente->setNombreCliente($registro['NOMBRE_CLIENTE']);
                $cliente->setApellido1($registro['APELLIDO1']);
                $cliente->setApellido2($registro['APELLIDO2']);
                $cliente->setNifNie($registro['NIF_NIE']);
                $cliente->setTipoCliente($registro['TIPO_CLIENTE']);
                $cliente->setTelefono1($registro['TELEFONO1']);
                $cliente->setTelefono2($registro['TELEFONO2']);
                $cliente->setIdCliente($registro['IDCLIENTE']);

                echo "<p>¡Bienvenido de nuevo, {$cliente->getNombreCliente()}!</p>";

                //return $cliente;
            }

            $tiempo_fin = microtime(true);
            echo "Tiempo empleado: " . ($tiempo_fin - $tiempo_inicio);

        } else {
            echo "<p>No existe la cookie RLID.</p>";
        }
    }
```

Al parecer no se guarda lo mismo en la cookie que en la base de datos... El resultado de la cookie es 120 caracteres pero en la base de datos, en phpmyadmin (con mariadb, por cierto, que no sé si tendrá que  ver), me muestra menos, diciendo al poner el ratón encima que el original son 60 caracteres (y eso que lo tengo como varchar con capacidad 255).

¡Un saludo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**¡SOLUCIONADO!**

El  problema estaba en la función **setRelogin()**, donde se puede ver que no es la misma variable la que mando a la base de datos que la que uso para crear la cookie:

```php
        setcookie("RLID", $combinacionRelogin, time()+60*60*24*365, "/");
```

```php
        $preparar->bindValue(":ReloginCliente", $combinacionSeguraRelogin,
```

De modo que la que he tenido que cambiar, obviamente, es la variable usada en la cookie, quedando así:

```php
        setcookie("RLID", $combinacionSeguraRelogin, time()+60*60*24*365, "/");
```